# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable while using pandas read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a csv with `pd.read_csv` method and I have a Type Error while using dtype :

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=separator, header=header_line, 
                 dtype={'id_technique':str,'type_opposition':str})
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: can you add the values you have assigned to `path`,  `separator` and `header_line`?

Comment: It worked perfectly with the other values, the problem comes from my last variable dtype

Comment: ok, can you post the full traceback?